# Get total avaiable RAM from the GRUB2 multiboot info structure

Tags: x86, kernel, i386, grub2

I managed to access the GRUB multiboot info structure (`multiboot_info_t`) in my i386 kernel, and there are two fields called `mem_lower` and `mem_upper` respectively. How do I use them to get the total available RAM (in bytes)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put, you can't.

The `mem_lower` and `mem_upper` are obsolete fields, referring to the [conventional memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_memory) and the [extended memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_memory).
Quoting the [specifications](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/multiboot/html_node/Boot-information-format.html#Boot%20information%20format):

> If *bit 0* in the `flags` word is set, then the `mem_*` fields are valid.
>   `mem_lower` and `mem_upper` indicate the amount of lower and upper memory, respectively, in <s>kilobytes</s> kibibytes.
>
> Lower memory starts at address 0, and upper memory starts at address 1 <s>megabyte</s> mebibyte. The maximum possible value for lower memory is 640 <s>kilobytes</s> kibibytes.
>
> The value returned for upper memory is maximally the address of the first upper memory hole minus 1 <s>megabyte</s> mebibyte. It is not guaranteed to be this value.

The two key aspects of this excerpt are:

1. The `flags` field needs to be tested before accessing the `mem_*` fields.
2. The `mem_lower` and `mem_upper` fields deal with memory holes very badly. Particularly `mem_upper` holds the size of the first continuous block of extended memory up to the first hole.

The second point is important enough to deserve a further discussion.
While the memory itself can be accessed, at the memory controller level<sup>1</sup>, as a continuous block it is not continuous at the memory subsystem level (what once was the [north-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northbridge_(computing)) and now is the [uncore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncore)).
The memory subsystem creates *holes* in the continuous address range assigned to memory either by simply not reclaiming specific sub-ranges - thereby wasting that memory - or by shifting the sub-ranges at higher addresses.

The reasons behind this seemingly strange behaviour have their roots deep in the historical evolution of the IBM PC.
A full discussion is out of topic but a short version can be laid out.
Initially, IBM reserved the first 640KiB of the 1MiB address space for the conventional memory and the remaining 384KiB for mapping the ROMs - including the BIOS ROM.
Note that the memory controller must not respond to read/write accesses above the 640KiB in order for them to get to the ROMs.

When the 1MiB barrier was broken (including or not the [HMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory_area) at will) the range from 640KiB to 1MiB couldn't be used for backwards compatibility.
This created the first hole: The standard hole.
The 286 had only a 24-bit address bus, thus a 16MiB address space.
At the same time, the [ISA bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Standard_Architecture) had already won against the [MCA bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Channel_architecture) and took place in the IBM PC compatible hardware.
Some ISA expansion cards came with expansion ROMs and the standard hole became exhausted, a 1MiB hole was reserved at the end of the 16MiB address space.
I call this hole the [ISA hole](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000933.htm).
Pretty much the same thing happened with PCI(e) when transitioning from 32-bit to 64-bit systems generating the [PCI hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_hole).

In addition to this holes, there are memory ranges that are read/writable but carry precious information laid out by the BIOS - namely the [ACPI tables](http://wiki.osdev.org/Category:ACPI).
Such ranges cannot be carelessly overwritten by the OS and thus must be reported to it.

All of this culminated in the [e820 service](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29#BIOS_Function:_INT_0x15.2C_EAX_.3D_0xE820) that instead of returning the memory size (which in the light of the discussion above makes no sense) it returns a *memory map* made of ranges with their type (available, reserved, reclaimable, bad, NVS).

This is also reflected in the GRUB `multiboot_info_t` structure fields `mmap_*` that you should use in place of the `mem_lower` and `mem_upper` as indicated in the [OSDev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Detecting_Memory_%28x86%29#Memory_Map_Via_GRUB).

---

<sup>1</sup> The [DIMMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIMM) are accessed with a rank, bank, column and row number but the memory controller usually makes this addressing linear and continuous.